# Как отменить влияние блока Div на другие элементы сайта?

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

Есть блок div, которому нужно задать фон и "подложить" под другой блок div, но когда я пытаюсь сделать это, новый div постоянно влияет на элементы сайта (отодвигает текст, вытесняет другие блоки). Мне нужно лишь чтобы он не влиял ни на что на сайте, и задать ему позиционирование относительно других блоков. Долго искал в интернете но все никак не мог найти, буду очень признателен за помощь (или хотя бы подскажите в какую сторону мне копать :) )

Comment: Установите свойства конкретному элементу по его id. Или проблема так не решилась?

Comment: @aleks.andr забыл упомянуть, что у всех элементов есть свои id :(

Comment: @Никита Ваш код?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Самый железобетонный вариант - position:absolute для вашего блока и position:relative для родителя. Поверено временем, опытом, практикой.

Answer (score 2):

```
.parent-div{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.background-div{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper{
  margin:auto;
  width:800px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#000,#ccc,#000);
}
.clear{
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.clear:after{
  content:'.';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.wrapper div{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  margin:5px;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#000,#ccc,#000);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clear"> 
   <div class=""></div>
   <div class=""></div>
   <div class=""></div>
   <div class=""></div>
   <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

я правильно понял ?